# Installing react-mic npm package in reactjs 18.2 version, shows dependency error between both

Tags: reactjs, npm

..\record> npm i react-mic

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: record@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!

I tried uninstalling package-lock.json and node_modules, re-install the npms. But, nothing seem to work. Also, don't want to build my projects over older version of reactjs just to support the react-mic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.